# Change MYSQL INT Value

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm real new to MySQL I've managed to create a table called maintenance with a default `int` value of 0 and I am trying to create a button which will change this value to one.

Here is a screenshot of what I have in phpmyadmin I just need to find some php code which will change the value to one I have tried many things but none have worked!

[image]

Just for your information it will be used so that when the value is 1 the maintenance page will be shown

Comment: you need the php code for this? or the sql query?

Comment: Well, whatever will do the trick i presume its bit of both php & mysql

Comment: a simple execution of "update gfx_maintenance set status = 1" will do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, what you have here is an empty table, with a row for status.

First, you need to insert the status row you have just created. Either do this through PHPMyAdmin (click insert at the top), or use the following SQL

```
INSERT INTO gfx_maintenance(status) VALUES(0)
```

Now, you actually have some data in the DB. To change this, either click the little pencil that appears in PHPMyAdmin, or use the following SQL:

```
UPDATE gfx_maintenance SET status=1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great Thanks, That works is it possible to only allow that once as once i go to the page it creates a new value every time

Comment: @user1907358 Then just don't create it in the page! Create it once somewhere (like PHPMyAdmin), then just update it every time instead. Remember that databases keep state between sessions!

Comment: Ok, Chill, i appreciate the help but this app that im building is going to be installable so it wouldn't really be a choice to do it via php my admin, i am just asking if it is posible to do it in a if statement or something.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't meaning it in an aggressive way. If it needs to be installable, distribute an install script with it or something. You need to create the schema, so insert the data at the same point.

Answer (score 1):

check the table and go to change option there you will find a default option and then select as defind option, enter you desired value